# how can save model by tensorflowlite

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite, mlops

i am try to save model by tesorflow lite but it give me this error how can solve this error or what it mean

### Summary on the non-converted ops:

- Accepted dialects: tfl, builtin, func
- Non-Converted Ops: 63, Total Ops 191, % non-converted = 32.98 %
- 63 ARITH ops

- arith.constant:   63 occurrences  (f32: 60, i32: 3)

  (f32: 10)
  (f32: 35)
  (f32: 17)
  (f32: 4)
  (f32: 1)
  (f32: 4)
  (uq_8: 52)
  (f32: 1)
  (f32: 1)

i am try to save as tf and covert it to tflite put give me same error
this my saved model as tf

```
mobilenet_model.save("saved_model", save_format="tf")
path = '/kaggle/working/saved_model'
saved_model = tf.saved_model.load(path)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(path)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
# Save the TensorFlow Lite model to a file
with open("EGY_TOUR_model.tflite", "wb") as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)
```

saved_model

variables

assets

keras_metadata.pb

fingerprint.pb

saved_model.pb